# Swagger UI is prompting for login even after ignoring in configuration after migrating to Java 17

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
 </dependency>

// Web Security Config 

public static final String[] excludedURLs = {
            "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/**"};
@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers(excludedURLs);
    }

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(XXXXAPIAuthenticationProvider)
                     .httpBasic()
                     .and()
                     .authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers(excludedURLs).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilter(getXXXXXBasicAuthenticationFilter())
                    .addFilterBefore(getOktaAuthFilter(), XXXXXXBasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

// Swagger Config

@Profile({"Test","STAGE"})
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {


    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    public static final String DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN = "/.*";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket=new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("com.XXXX.XXXX.controllers"))
                .paths(regex("/.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
        docket = docket.select()
                .paths(regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))
                .build();

        return docket;
    }
```

I have gone through below posts

Why does springfox-swagger2 UI tell me "Unable to infer base url."

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2191

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2907

[Unable to infer base url... springfox-swagger2 version 2.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280202/unable-to-infer-base-url-springfox-swagger2-version-2-9-2)

Please let me know what am I missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old swagger ( <= 2.9.2  or  v1/docs, v2/docs ) is not working with Java 17 or higher version hence I upgraded the Swagger to use open API.
Added below maven dependency in application pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.15</version>
  </dependency>
```

Removed all swagger related dependency related to version 2.9.2 and also no need to explicitly define SwaggerConfig.java Removed this class.

Just permitALL paths "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**" in spring security configuration as below and swagger UI is able to open without prompting any authentication.

```
public static final String[] excludedURLs = {"/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**"};

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(xxxAPIAuthenticationProvider)
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(excludedURLs).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

   return http.build();

}
```